# mysql php Cannot take foreign key value

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have a problem with my php code.. there are 3 tables for a recruitment system.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `members` (
   `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `username` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
   `password` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
   `cpassword` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
   `email` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
   `role` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)'
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=60 ;
```

The candidate table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `candidate` (
  `fullname` varchar(35) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `webpage` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `tel` int(35) NOT NULL,
  `nationality` varchar(35) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `position` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `interviewed` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'No',
  `rating` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `c_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`c_id`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=135 ;
```

The academic table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `academic_candidate` (    
    `degree` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
    `exp_years` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
    `comment1` varchar(300) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
    `proposed_positions` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
    `research_years` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
    `comment2` varchar(300) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
    `department` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
    `a_id` int(25) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `c_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`a_id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `id` (`a_id`),
    KEY `uid` (`uid`),
    KEY `c_d` (`c_id`),
    KEY `c_id` (`c_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=40 ;`
```

### -- Constraints for table `academic_candidate`

`ALTER TABLE`academic_candidate
  `ADD CONSTRAINT`academic_candidate_ibfk_1`FOREIGN KEY (`uid`) REFERENCES`members`(`uid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT`academic_candidate_ibfk_2`FOREIGN KEY (`c_id`) REFERENCES`candidate`(`c_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;`

--

### -- Constraints for table `candidate`

`ALTER TABLE`candidate
  `ADD CONSTRAINT`candidate_ibfk_1`FOREIGN KEY (`uid`) REFERENCES`members`(`uid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;`

--

Now, I use this query in order to store the values in the table academic_candidate

```
session_start();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM academic_candidate WHERE degree = '$degree'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$count  = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count > 0){ 
    echo "You ALready complete the form </br>";
    header("Location:../candidate/candidate_index.php");
}
else{
        $degree =($_POST['degree']);
        $exp_years = ($_POST['exp_years']);
        $comment1 = ($_POST['comment1']);
        $proposed_positions = ($_POST['proposed_positions']);
    $research_years=($_POST['research_years']);
    $comment2=($_POST['comment2']);
    $department=($_POST['department']);

   $uid=($_SESSION['uid']);


    $query1 = "INSERT INTO academic_candidate

                (degree,exp_years,comment1,proposed_positions,research_years,comment2,department,uid,c_id)
                SELECT
                 '$degree','$exp_years','$comment1','$proposed_positions','$research_years','$comment2','$department','$uid','$c_id'
                    FROM  candidate         
                 WHERE  uid='$uid' AND c_id='$c_id'  ";


    $result = mysql_query($query1);

    if(!$result){
        echo "Error";
        die (mysql_error());                                          
    }   

    else{
        header("Location:../candidate/view_application.php");
    }

}
```

My problem is that stores all the values on the table academic_candidate table but the c_id is 0 . What can I do in order to take the candidate.c_id?

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: I am new in programming and I can't understand  what you exactly mean.

Comment: You don't seem to have a foreign key defined.

Comment: He means you shouldn't be using mysql_ functions in new code

Comment: @JamieTaylor but w3schools said I should...

Comment: Oh, well if they're suggesting we continue, we best had, right? :D

Comment: have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp for foreign key constraints

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD sorry i forgot to post them:    `ALTER TABLE `academic_candidate`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `academic_candidate_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`uid`) REFERENCES `members` (`uid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `academic_candidate_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`c_id`) REFERENCES `candidate` (`c_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
    
--
-- Constraints for table `candidate`
--
ALTER TABLE `candidate`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `candidate_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`uid`) REFERENCES `members` (`uid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--`

Comment: You didn't start the $c_id variable.

Comment: @fagace  I noticed that , but because it is a value that is stored in another table I don't how to start it..Any idea?

Comment: Ok, if I'm not wrong you are trying to send a form with all that data. I don't know but you should get candidate information from the form and then validate that information and create the candidate or get from that table.

Comment: @fagace  Yes that  I want but I don't know how.

Comment: It would be helpful if you print all the $_POST content. You can do that with this command print(json_encode($_POST));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing literal values to your `INSERT INTO` statement.

Consider the difference:

```
SELECT 'bar' FROM foo;

SELECT bar FROM foo;
```

[Here's a demo on SQLFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7df7f/3)

Looking at your query:

```
SELECT '$degree'
```

Is not the same as:

```
SELECT degree
```

One of these is simply echoing whatever value you pass in, the other is actually selecting a column from the DB.

Comment: Thank you very much.. I solved finally the problem that I was thinking about the solution for days...